# count each letter in a string and letter frequency is greater than 2 then remove that word using php

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have to find the occurence of each letter in a string.for example,see the below given string
     $string="have a wonderful day for entirely different people";
        i have find occurence of each letter in string
         if letter occurs more than two times in a word,then remove that word from string.if anybody knows please help.

```
      <?php
            $string="have a wonderful day for entirely different people,sss greeetings";
       $s= str_split($string,1);
array_count_values($s);
            ?>
```

Comment: its not homework, am also trying to learn.you know it?

Comment: If it's not homework, what is it? It doesn't seem like a real-world application. Anyway, the way to learn to program is to program, not copy what others do.

Comment: Do you mean if the letter appears more than twice consecutively? Or would you want to remove each occurrence of 's' in Mississippi? I also agree that the real world applications of this seem limited to homework assignments.

Comment: Here's a hint: if you convert a string to an array of characters you can use `array_count_values()` to count the repetitions.

Comment: array_count_values counts words ,not letters.

Comment: @user7441072 First you change the string to an array, e.g. `"have"` becomes `["h", "a", "v", "e"]`. Then you use `array_count_values`.

Comment: @Ryankozak  i have to find count of each letter in string and also for eg: if s occurs more than 2, Mississippi then remove that word from string

Comment: What about `entirely`, since it has two `e`?

Comment: One of the tenets of SO is that you should show at least a minimal amount of effort.

Comment: You can use `explode()` to split the string into an array of words, and then use `str_split()` to convert each word into an array of characters.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't make any sense. You would be removing fully valid words from a string, and MAYBE some invalid words, but that's going to leave you with a sentence that doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Barmar if e occurs more than 2,then remove that word too

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Good point. Use `preg_split()` to use anything but letters as the delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example to help you get started.
https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_user.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_user.php
/**
 * Substrings and character counts
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421608/count-each-letter-in-a-string-and-letter-frequency-is-greater-than-2-then-remove
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


// ORIGINAL TEST DATA
$str = "have a wonderful day for entirely different people,sss greeetings";

// NORMALIZE COMMA TO MATCH BLANK SEPARATORS
$str = str_replace(',', ' ', $str);

// AN ARRAY OF WORDS
$arr = explode(' ', $str);

// EXAMINE EACH WORD, REMOVE THOSE WITH MORE THAN TWO DUPLICATED LETTERS
foreach ($arr as $key => $wrd)
{
    $cca = count_chars($wrd, 1);
    foreach ($cca as $chr)
    {
        if ($chr > 2) unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}

// RECONSTRUCT
$new = implode(' ', $arr);

// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
echo PHP_EOL . $str;
echo PHP_EOL . $new;
```

Comment: Thank You so much

Comment: But now the string is missing all of it's commas whoops

Comment: And this also doesn't allow for any other types of ways people break up words in strings such as `\r, \t, \n and \f`

Answer (score 2):

Try this function to remove all words with more than 1 common letter, this will also keep the string structure like commas.

```
$string = "have a wonderful day for entirely different people,sss greeetings";

echo removeDuplicateLetterWords($string);

function removeDuplicateLetterWords($str) {
    //convert all words in string to an array
    $words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);

    //declare an array that will be filled with words to remove
    $removeWords = array();

    //loop through each word
    foreach($words as $word) {

        //split word into an array of letters
        $letters = str_split($word);

        //loop through all letters
        foreach($letters as $letter) {

            //checks word to see if it has more than 1 of any letter
            if(substr_count($word, $letter) > 1) {
                //if word has multiple of a letter, add it to the "removeWords" array
                //if it's not already added
                if(!in_array($word, $removeWords)) $removeWords[] = $word;
            }
        }
    }

    //loop through removeWords array
    foreach($removeWords as $value) {
        //replace all of removeWords with an empty string
        $str = str_replace($value, "", $str);
    }

    //return string with none of the words d from removeWords
    return $str;
}
```

Here is the function without the comments as they were only there to explain to OP what was going on :P

```
function removeDuplicateLetterWords($str) {
    $words = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);
    $removeWords = array();
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $letters = str_split($word);
        foreach($letters as $letter) {
            if(substr_count($word, $letter) > 1) {
                if(!in_array($word, $removeWords))
                    $removeWords[] = $word;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($removeWords as $value) {
        $str = str_replace($value, "", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

**Side note**: This counts anything that is not a letter as a word delimiter.

Comment: i got this error Warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in F:\xampp\htdocs\az\index.php on line 24

Comment: my fault @user7441072, I had a typo, fixed in updated code

Comment: @user7441072 If my answer helped you the most feel free to mark it as correct :)